# Magento 2 - Set custom attribute value on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, cart, product-attribute, custom

**In Magento 1.x**

I have created following function in `Namespace/Modulename/Model/Observer.php`

```
public function salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute($observer){

        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $quoteItem->setCustomerProductPoints($product->getCustomerProductPoints());
    }
```

Called this function in `Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml`

```
    <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <product_point_quote>
                        <class>productpoint/observer</class>
                        <method>salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute</method>
                    </product_point_quote>
                </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

Also Have converted my custom attribute **quote to order** and from **order to quote** by using following code in `config.xml`

```
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <customer_product_points>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
            <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
            <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
        </customer_product_points>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <customer_product_points>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
            <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
            <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
        </customer_product_points>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
```

**In Magento 2**

I tried doing the same thing in Magento 2 but not able to get details of product.

I tried with following code:

`Namespace/Modulename/Observer/salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute.php`

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;


class salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $cartQuote= $this->cart->getItems()->getData();
        $prod= $this->product->getData();
        echo '<pre>';print_r($prod); exit;
    }
}
```

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_save_after">
        <observer name="set_checkout_quote_id" instance="Magento\Checkout\Observer\SalesQuoteSaveAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`etc/fieldset.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Object/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_item">
            <field name="product_point">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
                <aspect name="to_invoice_item" />
                <aspect name="to_shipment_item" />
                <aspect name="to_cm_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_item">
            <field name="product_point">
                <aspect name="to_quote_item" />
                <aspect name="to_invoice_item" />
                <aspect name="to_shipment_item" />
                <aspect name="to_cm_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Using the above code I am getting values of attributes in cart but not getting my custom attribute value. When I try to print Product Data it returns null.

The code works well with Magento 1.9. How do I make it work with Magento 2.0.2?

How to set `custom attribute` and display it cart page in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Magento 2**

Change the following code:

`Namespace/Modulename/Observer/salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute.php`

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;


class salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{
   protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $interface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quote,
        \CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->objectManager = $interface;
        $this->quote = $quote;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $quoteItem->setCustomAttribute($product->getCustomAttribute());
    }
}
```

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">

            <event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
                <observer
         name="product_point_quote"
         instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute"/>
            </event>
</config>
```

Create `catalog_attributes.xml` in `etc` to convert attribute to `quote`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="custom_attribute"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

This will bring your attribute on **Cart Page**

Comment: It is also possible by the way to add almost any custom data you need in QuoteItem object  by using:
`$quoteItem->setData('categoryData', $categoryData);` - in observer `execute()` method. For this you don't need to add anything in `catalog_attributes.xml`

Comment: how to add select option html tag in checkout cart page?

Answer (score 11):

No need to create any **Observe**, you can get it by simple below code.

Just need to create `{MODULE_NAME}/etc/catalog_attributes.xml` with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="custom_attribute"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

You can get custome attribute in `/templates/cart/item/default.phtml` with below code.

```
echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('custom_attribute');
```

Comment: Nice answer. Worked like charm

Comment: Thx, it saved my day :)

Comment: Thanks, It works