# Magento 2 - can not get custom attribute in product for add to cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-attribute

I want to add remark input text field in checkout page
I follow [Magento 2 - Set custom attribute value on cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108982/magento-2-set-custom-attribute-value-on-cart-page) to set custom attribute in quote_item.

In configurable.phtml

```
    <div class="field configurable required">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="remark" id="remark">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In catalog_attribute.xml

```
<group name="quote_item">
    <attribute name="remark"/>
</group>
```

In SalesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $quoteItem->setRemark($product->getRemark());
}
```

But `$product->getRemark()` is `null`, inside `/checkout/cart/add/` do I need to set remark in product directly from http request?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="remark"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Set the product attribute directly to `$quoteItem`. You don't have to set it manually.

Have a look inside `$quoteItem->getData('remark')` it should be already there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a magic method, try accessing the value through getData().

```
$product->getData('remark');
```